# How to get client / user ip address?

Tags: javascript, ip-address, load-balancing, clientip

Is it possible to get the ip address of the user (visitor of my website) **without using server side language** like PHP?

I have a problem while using the server language (PHP) because of load balancer for my server. I tried **http_x_forwared_for** that is also not retrieving the perfect ip address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){
   alert(data.host);
});
```

Comment: Service is unavailable.

Comment: jQuery.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (data) {
console.log(data);
document.getElementById('ip').innerHTML = data.ip;

Answer (score -5):

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
    }

IN PHP :)
```

Comment: Question asks for JS

Comment: The question SPECIFICALLY asks for a solution `without using server side language like PHP`